# Excel formula which returns the cell value for the intersection of rows with specific name and specific column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a Microsoft Excel formula which returns a cell value for the last cell that is located in a specific column and in the same time intersects rows with a given name?

Comment: A couple of notes on doing a self answer question(which is encouraged here).  First the Question should be able to stand on its own, ie it should be a [mcve].  This question really does not meet that standard.  It should not only have test data and expected output but what was tried and failed.  Second, make sure there are not duplicate questions out there.

Answer (score 2):

With Office 365, We can filter the range and return an array of all that meet the criteria.  Then use TAKE to grab the last one:

```
=TAKE(FILTER(H:H,((A:A=<row_name>)*(H:H<>""),""),-1)
```

Another option that works in all Versions after 2010  This uses AGGREGATES ability to work with arrays and ignore any errors cause by dividing by `0`.  The 14 grabs the largest row number where the `(A:A=<row_name>)*(H:H<>"")` returns a `1`.  It then passes that row number to the INDEX:

```
=INDEX(H:H,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW(H:H)/((A:A=<row_name>)*(H:H<>"")),1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Generic formula expression:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(<row_header_range>=<string_value>)*(<column_range><>""),<column_range>)
```

and the example (in Ukrainian locale, where `,` is replaced by `;`:

```
=LOOKUP(2;1/((A:A="Row_name")*(H:H<>""));H:H))
```

`LOOKUP` function searches for the last non-empty cell in the column, based on the specified search criteria.

Comment: Now, a note on the answer.  Code only answers are a constant discussion on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390313/code-only-answers and most are of the opinion they should be downvoted.  I am not one of those, but there are those out there.  So take a moment to explain what this formula does.  You should take the point that these are separate and you are explaining the answer to someone who does not know.

Comment: What is in col A and col H ? Then explain what your answer does.

Comment: @ScottCraner Updated per your suggestion, thanks.